# How to allow some tags but block others for XSS

Tags: php, security, xss

I want to allow some tags like `<p> <ul> <li> <b> <strong>` I have a specific list. But I also want to protect from XSS attacks so I need to use escaping. How can I do it so that I allow those specific tags, but escape everything else?

Comment: If you're making a syntax engine thing, why not use your own syntax blocks, like `{p}` or `[p]`? Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Most frequently recommended is [`HTMLPurifier`](http://www.google.com/search?q=HTMLPurifier), because that contains heaps of workarounds to prevent all kinds of XSS abuse. It filters out tags and attributes that other solutions might miss. It's a bit of configuration work, and maybe overkill in some settings. But it's certainly the safest approach.

You can configure an allowed list with it, but you could as well still apply the `strip_tags()` method by @yc. But not alone by itself! ***Only in conjunction*** with HTMLPurifier!

Comment: Deleting my answer. +1. `strip_tags` alone is a lazy answer, and a dangerous one for less informed folks.

Comment: It's still a good reminder. And for stripping *all* html tags it's perfectly fine. It's just the exceptions that make it less applicable in that example.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function in Drupal called [filter_xss](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/filter_xss/7) that you can use as a (fantastic) example if you want something sophisticated. Otherwise just use the [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.